# I am trying to set a value to an already string labeled radio button. I do not understand my mistake

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton, graphical-programming

```
public class RoomListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        double roomtype; 

        if (event.getSource() == room1)
            roomtype = 60;
        else if (event.getSource() == room2)
            roomtype = 75;
        else 
            roomtype = 100;
    }

}


public class CostListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        double NightLength, roomNumber, cost;
        String NightText = NumberOfNights.getText();
        String RoomText = NumberOfRooms.getText();

        NightLength = Double.parseDouble(NightText);
        roomNumber = Double.parseDouble(RoomText);

        RoomListener.actionPerformed(RoomType);
        cost = roomtype * NightLength * roomNumber;

        CostCalculation.setText(Double.toString(cost));
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        CostCalculation.setText(fmt.format(cost));
    }
}
```

Comment: so what's the problem? what error are you getting?

Comment: for RoomListener.actionPerformed(roomtype); - it says that "The method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in the type HotelBookingPanel.RoomListener is not applicable for the arguments (double)"

Answer (score 0):

> RoomListener.actionPerformed(RoomType);

1. This isn't a `static` method. You can't call it using the class name.
2. What is `RoomType`? If it isn't an `ActionEvent`, then it won't work. Look at the method.

   ```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
   ```
3. You really shouldn't be calling out to another listener's actionPerformed, or at least I can't think of a reason to. You need to add a `new RoomListener()` onto your RadioButtons. Though, I'd suggest you look into a RadioGroup class, and reading the JavaDoc for the correct listener which lets you determine the source of the selected radio button.
4. Nothing is returned from this method. `double roomtype` is a local variable and it is discarded (garbage collected) when you exit this method. Maybe you meant to modify a member variable? `this.roomtype`? 
   Along with that point - I can't tell what `room1` and `room2` are here... They don't seem to be accessible.

   ```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
   {
       double roomtype; 

       if (event.getSource() == room1)
           roomtype = 60;
       else if (event.getSource() == room2)
           roomtype = 75;
       else 
           roomtype = 100;
   }
   ```